# Как исправить ошибку в коде? Не заменяет строку

Tags: python, строки

До 41 строки все работает правильно, но после -нет. Программа должна заменить фразу, но почему-то все остается в исконном виде.[![][1]][1]

**Задание**

Напишите программу, формирующую простую форму для письма на основе входной
информации.

Dear first_name!
How are you? Everything is okay with me. I miss you! Have you seen friend_name? If so, please, tell him/her
to call me. By the way congratulations on your age birthday! Some phrase regarding age.
Yours sincerely,
sender_name
Текст, помеченный черным курсивом будет зависеть от пользовательского ввода (это имя
получателя письма, имя отправителя письма, имя некоего друга, пол этого друга, возраст
получателя письма, некая фраза, касаемо возраста).
Для указания пола друга пользователь может ввести 0 (Мужской) или 1 (Женский). В вашем
коде должна быть булевая переменная isMale, которая созранит пол друга. В зависимости
от значения данной переменной фразу tell him to call me нужно использовать, если у друга
пол мужской, а tell her to call me , если у друга пол женский.
Для указания возраста пользователь должен ввести год рождения адресата. В коде вам
нужно вычислить возраст и присвоить его переменной age.
Ваша программа должна вывести на экран строку: " By the way congratulations on your age
birthday!". Если значение переменной age меньше или равно 0 или больше или равно 110,
выведите на экран строку error («you are joking»). Добавьте в ваше письмо следующие строки.
Если вашему другу меньше 17 лет, напишите: " Next year you'll be 13" (в зависимости от
возраста). Если вашему другу 18 лет, напишите: " You can vote now". Если вашему другу
больше 60 лет, напишите: " Hope you do not get bored on your retirement". Убедитесь, что ваша
программа правильно обрабатывает каждое из этих значений. И в результате выдает
строку со всеми нужными данными

````
sender_name = str (input("sender name:"))
friend_name = str (input("friend name:"))
#text first version
text1 = '''Dear first_name!
How are you? Everything is okay with me. I miss you! Have you seen friend_name? If so, please, tell him/her to call me. By the way congratulations on your age birthday! Some phrase regardingage.
Yours sincerely,
sender_name'''
birt_year = int(input("birth year:"))
year = 2022
some_age_phrase = str("")
is_M = bool
age = year - birt_year
age = str(age)
error = "are you joking"
#replacing name to input name
a = text1.replace('first_name',first_name)
b = a.replace('friend_name',friend_name)
c = b.replace('age',age)
d = c.replace('sender_name',sender_name)
#replacing friend gender to input gender
#checking and replacing gender, error explanation to a user
try:
    friend_gender = int(input("0- male 1- female:"))
    if friend_gender == 0:
        is_M = True
        is_M = 'him'
        e = d.replace('him/her',is_M)
        print(e)
    elif friend_gender == 1:
        is_M= False
        is_M ='her'
        e = d.replace('him/her',is_M)
        print(e)
    else:
        print("No such gender supported")
except ValueError:
    print("Only numbers! 0 or 1")

#error here
if age <= "17" and age !="0" :
     text1.replace ("Some phrase regardingage","Next year you'll be")
elif age >= '18' :
    text1.replace ("Some phrase regardingage",'You can vote now')
elif age >= '60' and age != '110':
    text1.replace ("Some phrase regardingage", " Hope you do not get bored on your retirement!")
else:
    print(error)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG8Zo.png
````

Comment: Помимо сравнения строковых переменных, что даёт часто странные эффекты, у вас вся логика сравнений странная. Вторая проверка полностью перекроет третью, третья почему-то исключает 110 (хотя живут и дольше), но вполне допустит 250, например.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны привести age к типу данных int, и сравнение производить с этим типом данных, а не с str. Python - не делает автоматические приведение типов, как бы это было в JS.

Либо сделайте ещё одну переменную для строкового возраста age(age_s), либо сделайте вот так:

```
if 0 <= int(age) <= 17 :
 text1.replace ("Some phrase regardingage","Next year you'll be")
elif  18 <= int(age) <= 60:
    text1.replace ("Some phrase regardingage",'You can vote now')
elif  60 <= int(age) <= 110:
    text1.replace ("Some phrase regardingage", " Hope you do not get bored on your retirement!")
else:
    print(error)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но, при изменении типа данных происходит другая ошибка связанная с другой переменной  c = b.replace('age',age)
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not int

Comment: @Dina, отредактировал ответ

Comment: В дальнейшем, если кол-во проверок увеличится будет разумно сделать приведение age = int(age) до условий, чтобы постоянно не приводить к типу Int